# NSXMLParser with multiple delegates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsxmlparser

I'm trying to parse an xml tree file whith multiple NSXMLParserDelegate parsers but I'm getting in the next issue.

My XML structure is something like that.

```
<Object1>
     <Name>Ricky</Name>
     <Surname>Woodstock</Surname>
     <Adress>
          <City>Los Angeles</City>
          <State>California</State>
          <Country>USA</Country>
     </Adress>
     <Items>
          <Item>
               <Id>1</Id>
               <Description>Sports Bag</Description>
               <Price>13.45</Price>
          </Item>
          <Item>
               <Id>2</Id>
               <Description>Baseball Cap</Description>
               <Price>6.90</Price>
          </Item>
     </Items>
     <Total>20.15</Total>
</Object1>
```

And my Issue is that when I changes delegates, it starts parsing not in top-level tag, instead it begins parsing on the first nested tag.

For example.

1. I begin parsing XML wih XMLObject parser which parses  element
2. When it reaches Adresss tag I set delegate to XMLAdressParser (and set XMLAdressParser's parent to self for returning) but XMLAdressParser begins parsing on  tag.
3. And almost with Items and Item tags.

I think it's normal cause of a Parser definition, but that's the question:

Is there any way for the delegate to start parsing in correspondint tag, like first one?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Sergio

Comment: Why are you using multiple delegates? A single one could process each part of the XML

Comment: I'm developing generic delegates for converting XML to NSObject quicky, or I'm trying it...

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using multiple delegates I suggest using a single delegate and having it distribute the work as you feel appropriate.

Comment: Multiple delegates are a valid way of parsing XML. This is barely an answer to his question.

Comment: He said NSXMLParser, that's how NSXMLParser works. If it was a generic XML parsing question I would have answered differently.

Comment: NSXMLParser supports multiple delegates as documented in the Apple documentation.  I think the original poster was looking for an example of how to use it (and so am I, for that matter)